# how to create dynamic library for ios project in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to xcode please can anyone tell how to create dynamic library for an ios project similar to (.so) files in android? I have found .dylib files for Os x but haven't found anything for ios.

Comment: `.framework` In the Xcode template choose dialogue check for library/framework

Comment: I have code in c++ for library. can i use it in .framework? can u explain this in detail? @MidhunMP

Comment: See my answer below. Frameworks can be used in both platforms: macOS and iOS. However, the specific code you put in them might differ, because of incompatibilities that might be specific to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html). There is a section for how to make frameworks with C++ code. Basically, you need to make C wrappers for your C++ interface, because of name mangling done by the C++ compiler.